# generating image on the fly with css and javascript

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I saw in twitter bootstrap's carousel sample that the `container marketing` img and `featurette` img are generated on the fly.

I am new to css, javascript and twitter bootstrap, could anyone please explain this? I'd love to know how it was done so that I can change it to generate my own image, thanks!

here's the javascript (I think so.. it is in `holder.js`):

```
var settings = {
    domain: "holder.js",
    images: "img",
    bgnodes: ".holderjs",
    themes: {
        "gray": {
            background: "#eee",
            foreground: "#aaa",
            size: 12
        },
        "social": {
            background: "#3a5a97",
            foreground: "#fff",
            size: 12
        },
        "industrial": {
            background: "#434A52",
            foreground: "#C2F200",
            size: 12
        }
    },
    stylesheet: ".holderjs-fluid {font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;font-family:sans-serif;margin:0}"
};
```

and here is the html part:

```
  <div class="featurette">
    <img class="featurette-image img-circle pull-right" data-src="holder.js/512x512">
    <h2 class="featurette-heading">First featurette heading. <span class="text-muted">It'll blow your mind.</span></h2>
    <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
  </div>
```

when view the image, its address looks something like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

EDIT:

Thanks everyone, for the answer!! it is due to all of your answers that lead me to figure out that the image is generated from the themes: { ... } in var settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with image data URIs, they are basically just images in text format, and they are not dependant on the CSS or JavaScript; it's really just the image's data encoded in character format.

You can generate them with various online tools like this [image to data uri convertor](http://websemantics.co.uk/online_tools/image_to_data_uri_convertor/).

The benefit of using them is that very small images can be inlined to the HTML, thus saving the browser from making extraneous HTTP requests and, if your HTML is well cahced, a aching solution as well. Keep in mind that they have their cons as well: they are pretty inefficient for large images, for example.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply Data-URIs images: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/data_URIs

They are images encoded directly in a URL format so you don't need to request them form a server.

You can test compiling images to data-uri on this site: http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker

Sass and Compass also have a helper to leverage the encoding directly in your stylesheets source (http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/inline-data/).